# HttpPost 500 error.(SimpleCode)

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, post

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?
Basically I am trying to input data into a table using Android and Php.
But I cant even get the php side to work because I am getting HTTP Error 500, does anyone see the error here?
Thanks!

>

```
<?php
/* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
 $con = mysql_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD);

mysql_select_db ( $DB_DATABASE, $con ) or die ( “Database Selection Failed”     );




//$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
//$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
//$givenname = $_REQUEST['givenname'];
//$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
//$phonenumber = $_REQUEST['phonenumber'];

$username = isset($_POST[‘username’]) ? $_POST[‘username’] : ”;
$password = isset($_POST[‘password’]) ? $_POST[‘password’] : ”;
$givenname = isset($_POST[‘givenname’]) ? $_POST[‘givenname’] : ”;
$email = isset($_POST[‘email’]) ? $_POST[‘email’] : ”;
$phonenumber = isset($_POST[‘phonenumber’]) ? $_POST[‘phonenumber’] : ”;



$flag['code']=0;
if ($result = mysql_query ( “INSERT INTO demo VALUES(‘$username’,    ‘$password’, `$givenname`, `$email`, ‘$phonenumber’)”, $con )) {
$flag [‘code’] = 1;
echo “hi”;
}

echo (json_encode ( $flag )) ;
mysql_close ( $con );

?>
```

Comment: Those quotes look odd to me: `‘, “, ”`...

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Fix those "smart" quotes:

```
<?php
/* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
 $con = mysql_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD);

mysql_select_db ( $DB_DATABASE, $con ) or die ( "Database Selection Failed"     );




//$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
//$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
//$givenname = $_REQUEST['givenname'];
//$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
//$phonenumber = $_REQUEST['phonenumber'];

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$givenname = isset($_POST['givenname']) ? $_POST['givenname'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$phonenumber = isset($_POST['phonenumber']) ? $_POST['phonenumber'] : '';



$flag['code']=0;
if ($result = mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO demo VALUES('$username',    '$password', `$givenname`, `$email`, '$phonenumber')", $con )) {
$flag ['code'] = 1;
echo "hi";
}

echo (json_encode ( $flag )) ;
mysql_close ( $con );

?>
```